# Airflow: skip line before bitshift operator

Tags: python, airflow

Is it possible to break lines between a bitfshift operator when setting Task dependencies in a DAG?

My DAG has 10 Tasks, and they all must be executed in sequence, with no parallelization.

I'd like to chain them in my code vertically, like below:

```
   task_1 \
>> task_2 \
>> task_3 \
>> task_n \
```

Instead of horizontally:

`task_1 >> task_2 >> task_3 >> task_n`

I tried the `\` character but I had no success with it.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have spaces after the backslash?

Comment: There's no spaces after `backslash`. Just checked it here

Comment: Have you tried the parentheses?

Comment: Just tried the `parenthesis`, and it worked! Thanks @GertjanBrouwer

Comment: Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61786368/5691525 :) You can just use a list containing all tasks and `chain` them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is (as far as I know) two ways to do this in Python.
The first being the backslash, which you already tried, the second being the parentheses. 
In your case it would look like this:

```py
foo = (task_1 >> task_2 >> task_3 >> task_n)
```

[PEP8 on maximum line length says:](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

When breaking your line keep in mind that your binary operator (>> in this case) always comes on the new line in front of the statment. This makes it a lot more readable e.g.

```py
foo = variable1 +
      variableThatIsVeryLong -
      var *
      varAverage
```

vs.

```py
foo = variable1
      + variableThatIsVeryLong
      - var
      * varAverage
```

This way it is immediately clear to the reader what operator is being used.

One possible reason the backslash is not working might be because of a space right after it.

Comment: Thanks for the PEP8 link. 

I didn't know I could solve this problem by using any of the three options mentioned in the docs. My resulting code looks like this (it needed no assignment also):

`(
     task_1
>> task_2
>> task_3
>> task_n
)`

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [chain](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/utils/helpers.py#L154) function from `airflow.utils.helpers` to chain linear dependencies.

Example:

```py
from airflow.utils.helpers import chain

tasks = [op1, op2, op3, op4, op5]
chain(*tasks)
```

is equivalent to:

```py
op1 >> op2 >> op3 >> op4 >> op5
```

Details: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#relationship-builders

Comment: `chain` seems to be the solution I was looking for since the beginning.


I used it to chain dynamically generated `task_ids` that are appended to a list.

Nevertheles, `chain` threw the error below in Airflow's UI:

`Chain not supported different length Iterable but get 55 and 63`

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this now